# Load and use a Mathematica Package via .Net code

Tags: c#, graph, wolfram-mathematica, package

I'm using C# to pass data to Mathematica and return Graphs:

```
MathKernel k = new MathKernel();
k.CaptureGraphics = true;
k.GraphicsFormat = "JPEG";
k.Compute("Show[Graphics[{Thick, Blue, Circle[{#, 0}] & /@ Range[4], Black, Dashed, Line[{{0, 0}, {5, 0}}]}]]");
pictureBox1.Image = k.Graphics[0];
```

[image]

This works until I need to use a Package. I'm seeing the raw Data is returned instead of an image:

```
StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder();
command.Append("fakedata01 = With[{n = DayCount[{2008, 01, 01}, {2011, 3, 27}]}, Transpose[{Array[DatePlus[{2008, 01, 01}, #] &, n, 0], #}] & /@ (100. + (Accumulate /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {8, n}]))];");
command.Append("Dimensions[%];");
command.Append("XYZLineGraph[fakedata01, Title -> \"Banks\\[CloseCurlyQuote] Share Prices\", Subtitle -> \"1 January 2008 = 100\", ScaleUnits -> \"Index\", DateLabelFormat -> \"Quarter1\", PartialLastYear -> 2.95/12, Footnotes -> {{\"*\", \"MSCI financials index\"}}, Sourcenotes -> {\"Bloomberg\"}, SpecialGridValues -> 100, PlotStyle -> {Red, XYZDarkBlue, XYZPink, XYZMauve, XYZPaleOrange, XYZTurquoise, Green, Gray}, Epilog -> {Red, Arrow[{{{2009, 3}, 30}, {{2009, 8}, 48}}], Text[\"Label\", {{2009, 3}, 25}]}]");

MathKernel k = new MathKernel();
k.CaptureGraphics = true;
k.GraphicsFormat = "JPEG";
k.Compute("Get[\"XYZ`XYZGraphs`\"];");
k.Compute("Get[\"XYZ`XYZUtilities`\"]");
k.Compute("Show[" + command.ToString() + "]");
pictureBox1.Image = k.Graphics[0];
```

The error is:

**Get::noopen: Cannot open XYZ`XYZGraphs`.**

I have installed the Packages in Mathematica so on startup they are available. When I run the command in Mathematica it gives me the expected output.

**Does anyone know how to load the Packages so they are available via a .Net call?**

These two lines dont work:

```
k.Compute("Get[\"XYZ`XYZGraphs`\"];");
k.Compute("Get[\"XYZ`XYZUtilities`\"]");
```

I've also tried the following and it has the same problem:

```
k.Compute("Get[\"XYZ`XYZGraphs`\"];Get[\"XYZ`XYZUtilities`\"];Show[" + command.ToString() + "]");
```

<sub>*I've already seen these threads but they are in Mathematica not in C#:*
[Load a mathematica package from within a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385317/load-a-mathematica-package-from-within-a-package)
[Building Application Packages with multple packages and references in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567980/building-application-packages-with-multple-packages-and-references-in-mathematic)</sub>

Comment: More info over [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19516/load-a-mathematica-package-via-net-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out, the full answer is over at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19516/load-a-mathematica-package-via-net-code

I evaluated $UserBaseDirectory in a Mathematica session. In that directory is the pre-established Applications folder where you are supposed to put your work. This is your private Applications folder.

Say you are doing extended work on TopicX. Create a TopicX folder in your private Applications folder. You can create subsidiary folders that contain your work and organize your notebooks on this topic.

Now make the BeginPackage statement in your package (which has the name XYZGraphs.m and is placed in theXYZ folder):

```
BeginPackage["XYZ`XYZGraphs`"]
```

Now you can load the package from anywhere by using:

```
<< XYZ`XYZGraphs`
```